How to install postgis in AWS EC2 AL2023 for postgres 15
I have a PostgreSQL server 15 in an EC2 AL2023. I want to add a PostGIS extension to the Postgresql server but I got No such file or directory. extension "postgis" message.
Commands like dnf -y install postgis[version] also not working. It says no match argument.
I tried to install Postgis manually following this instruction postgis_installation
I got Missing autoconf! error when trying to run sh autogen.sh
Does anyone know how to pass this step? Or is there any clear instruction for installing Postgis to AL2023?
